# NHibernate: identifier of an instance of object was altered from x to y

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I have a situation with nhibernate. I have this piece of code:

```
private void UnlinkProductsFromPriceAgreement(NameValueCollection collection, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    // Get the price agreement id
    int priceAgreementId = collection.GetInt("Id");

    foreach (int productId in collection.GetIds("unlinkProductsList"))
    {
        // Get the product price
        IProductPrice productPrice =
            ProductPriceRepository.Find(p => p.PriceAgreement.Id == priceAgreementId && p.Product.ProductId == productId).FirstOrDefault();

        // Remove the product price
        ProductPriceRepository.Delete(productPrice);
    }
}
```

I get this exception when I run this code:

```
Qe.Common.Core.Exceptions.PersistencyException ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of Qe.Vending.Core.DomainObjects.Product was altered from 210036 to 0
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.CheckId(Object obj, IEntityPersister persister, Object id, EntityMode entityMode) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.cs:line 111
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.GetValues(Object entity, EntityEntry entry, EntityMode entityMode, Boolean mightBeDirty, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.cs:line 84
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Its difficult to know exactly why you are getting this error without seeing the mappings. Please can you add them to the question?

Comment: We don't have the code for your ProductPriceRepository.

Comment: I just started getting this with the latest NHibernate, but didn't have it with the previous version.  I swear I'm on 3.3.3 now, but Visual Studio still reports it was 3.3.1.